# Как отловить окончание работы асинхронной функции в javascript

Tags: javascript

Имеется форма вид которой меняется при установке checkbox'а происходит это в асинхронной функции которая подгружает данные с сервера. менять код ее не могу.
нужно в зависимости от вида заполнять поля формы. 
Идея была в следующем : перехват изменеия checkbox, вызов в своей функции оригинальной функции. повторная установка перехватчика и заполнение полей формы в зависимости от выбранной модели. 
данный алгорит отрабатывает ровно 1 раз. из за того что в момент обработки новый вид формы еще оказывается не подгружен. Если выполнять код с помошью дебагера то все отрабатывается.
вот пример

```
function SetClick(){
    console.log("Setting");
    ML("$FDFGDF","D44-54","X143","DG-E$#"); // заполняем поля
    $("[name=A18]").removeAttr("onclick");
    $("[name=A18]").click(function(e){
        console.log("CLICK");
        __doResPage(); // оригинальная функция
        SetClick(); // возвращаем обработчик
    });
};
```

пример формы (но он не особо и важен)

```
<form id="frm" method="post" action="rest.php">
    <input type="checkbox" checked name="A18" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(__doResPage(),0)">Переключалка формы</input>
    <input type="text" name="A123"/>
    <input type="text" name="A17"/>
    <input type="submit">Отправить</input>
</form>
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос, если судить по заголовку - самый типовой и популярный вопрос начинающих в javascript. Пожалуй даже популярнее чем "сделайте мне лабу". Ответ на него здесь давали 100500 раз. Если вкратце, то варианта два. Либо вызывать действия, требующие ответа, в коллбеке ответа. Либо промисифицировать вашу асинхронную операцию.

Comment: как я понял `__doResPage()` ваша асинхронная функция, передаете в неё, функцию в которой вызываете `SetClick()`. А в функции в ответе от сервера, вызываете вашу функцию. В принципе `Утка` правильно вам написал

Comment: Вдогонку ссылка про "вариант#2": https://learn.javascript.ru/promise

Comment: а что значит _возвращаем обработчик_? если функция просто добавит еще один такой же?

Comment: eventlistener напиши http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Answer (score 1):

Можно закрыться then'ом

```
__doResPage().then(function(data) {
  // вернуть какой-то код
  }, function(err) {
  // ф-ция вернула ошибку err
});
```

[Подробне на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: Ставлю перо из хвоста на то, что сейчас асинхронная операция топикстартера не возвращает промис и "закрыться thenом" не выйдет

Comment: возможно, ф-ции то пока никто кроме автора не видел

Comment: Асинхронная функция не моя и не возвращает ничего. Она меняет содержимое формы.

Comment: И кстати then не подойдет т.к. целевая платфома не умеет его судя по документации